# How can I avoid overusing "I" and "I'm" in a first person short story?

Tags: creative-writing, short-story, grammar, pronouns

The story I'm writing uses 'I' and 'I'm' way too much, and it's really obvious. The problem is that I cannot find words to replace the two, and when I do, it always changes and bends what I'm trying to portray, making it extremely difficult and confusing to understand.

Is there a way for me to stop using them so much? Is there a way to make them less noticeable and less obvious?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you look at some questions about this problem in the third person and see if they help? You may want to [edit] to add more details about what your problematic wording is. [How to avoid using "he/she/it" repetitively in action](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/34417/34330), [How to cut down on using too many pronouns (he, she, his etc.) while writing paragraphs](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/52850/34330), and [How can I make my roleplay sentences more interesting, and less lengthy?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/27161/34330)

Comment: In addition to following the advice in the answers below, I recommend you try to read as many first-person novels as you can. For instance, novels in the "noir" and "hardboiled" detective genres are very often written in first-person. Autobiographies too ;)

Comment: Not likely to be what you are looking for, so commenting instead of an answer, but one option would be to make your first-person narrator an [illeist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illeism). Of course, that changes the whole tone of the writing, and you end up potentially overusing the narrator’s name instead of first-person pronouns, but it is a possibility to consider.

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time to answer and comment!, they have been very helpful to me!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### The way to stop overusing 'I' and 'I'm' is to examine the words following those terms.

Usually, they are [filter](https://www.masterclass.com/articles/how-to-avoid-unnecessary-filter-words-in-your-writing) words -- thought, felt, heard, et cetera -- and are putting a kind of layer between your 1st person narrator and the reader. By writing more intimately, the filter words disappear

For example, 'I felt angry because they were out of cookies' becomes 'No Cookies! Don't tell me there are no more cookies.' or 'Is it too much to ask for there to be enough cookies for everyone.' or 'Never enough cookies. #Deleted bakers!'

And, 'I thought I'm getting fat' becomes 'These pants are too tight?'

Okay, fine, they are lousy examples. You're not paying for my A-game! I thought to myself as I typed out my answer to another question on that online forum.

Not that you should be getting rid of all I and I'm. They are useful for focusing the moment on the character, especially when the character experience is mixed in with narrative passages. As in 'I'm short. Not that it's all bad. Many famous people were short -- Alexander the Great 3'6" Jack the Giant Killer 2'10". The world can crap on short people, thinking them small and insignificant. Just let them go on like that. Never thinking, I'm hiding under their bed with a knife.'

Starts intimate. Drifts slowly away, feels kind of like a character thinking, but is a great way to introduce world building and exposition, then pull it back into intimate with 'I'm under their bed.'

Comment: IOW, don't narrate "I felt X" but show stream of conscious.  And you don't have to put "I thought," when you do so, if it's a consistent thing for the whole chapter.

Comment: @JDługosz, not so much stream of consciousness, because that's a whole thing in itself (and one I don't understand).  But show the moment with directness and intimacy

Answer (score 20):

## Remember your first person POV is the narrator:

When I am describing what is going on in third person, it wouldn't occur to address people about me as narrator. But in many ways, first person POV is simply third person where the narrator also gets to be one of the characters.

The examples that EDL uses in his answer are very good (+1). It's all about keeping the perspective as much as possible in the observation, not in the action. So "I opened the creaky door and I found it to be a jarring noise," becomes "The door opened with a jarring creak." The thinking is to have the character describe the story like a narrator. Then the only places where you need to use I/my/I'm/me is where you are describing the actions of narrator-as-character, or to clarify who is performing a specific task and it's not otherwise clear.